# How to copy multiple files names from folder to listbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to get the names for some PDF files in a specific path to a list box by VB.Net

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(
         My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments,
         FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, PathText & "\" & "\01-Fabrication" & "*.PDF")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(foundFile)
Next
```

I searched and found the above one but it's nothing.

Comment: Your first parameter needs to include pathtext and the 01-fabrication, and then the searchpattern should only be "*.PDF"

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(
         My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments,
         FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.PDF")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(foundFile)
Next
```